# SignPost error using OAuth and get Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of

Tags: android, magento-1.7, signpost

I am accessing magento backend from my android app using consumer. and i am getting following response from the magento after authentication done manually.

```
object(Zend_Http_Response)#16 (5) {
["version":protected] => string(3) "1.1"
 ["code":protected] => int(200)
 ["message":protected] => string(2) "OK"
["headers":protected] => array(6) {
["Date"] => string(29) "Mon, 10 Mar 2014 05:55:59 GMT"
["Server"] => string(45) "Apache/2.4.7 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1e PHP/5.5.6"
["X-powered-by"] => string(9) "PHP/5.5.6"
["Connection"] => string(5) "close"
["Transfer-encoding"] => string(7) "chunked"
["Content-type"] => string(31) "application/json; charset=utf-8"
}
["body":protected] => string(27184) "6a23
{"16":         {"entity_id":"16","attribute_set_id":"38","type_id":"simple","sku":"n2610","model":"2610","dimension":"4.1 x 1.7 x 0.7 inches ","description":"something"}}0"}
```

How to parse above response in android app using signpost jar.In android I am using SignPost for java OAuth library and there manually I am passing Consumer Key,Consumer Secret Key,Access Token, and Access Token Secret.
my java file is below

```
package com.example.dukano;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.Console;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

import oauth.signpost.OAuthConsumer;
import oauth.signpost.commonshttp.CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class JSONParser {
static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jObj = null;
static String json = "";
OAuthConsumer  consumer;

public JSONParser(){
    consumer = new CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer("4fd325e8273924df5f48f978a3f8e556","46be40812031f40645788ee90894efbe");
    consumer.setTokenWithSecret("ca269640a3629a1d65af59d16058d91c", "f23ad8ba9646dbb28be5255c9faca0e1");
} //constructor

public JSONObject getJSONFromURL(String url)
{
    try
    {
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);
        request.setHeader("Accept", "text/xml");
        consumer.sign(request);
        org.apache.http.HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request); // error caught here


        HttpEntity httpEntity = response.getEntity();

        //String responsebody= EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
        //System.out .println(responsebody+"hello world");
        is = httpEntity.getContent();

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    try
    {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }

        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
        Log.i("JSON", json);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {}
     try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);   //showing parse error here        
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("my JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }
    return jObj;
    }
}
```

I found in debug mode that

```
org.apache.http.HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
```

above statement when execute then it goes to try catch following :

```
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);   //showing parse error here        
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("my JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }
```